# Determining a line integral of $\frac{p'}{p}$ with $p$ being a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, line-integrals

Let $p: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial, and $R > 0$ large enough, so that all roots of $p$ lie within $B_R(0)$ (the open ball with radius $R$ around $0$).

I now want to determine:

$$\int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} dz$$

So far, I thought of setting $\gamma: [0, 2π] \to \mathbb{C}, t \mapsto R e^{i t}$ (parameterizing the circle with radius $R$), and setting $p(z) = a_n z^n + ... + a_1 z + a_0$.

Now I guess, one *could* solve this integral "on foot", by substituting $p(z) = a_n z^n + ... + a_1 z + a_0$ and $p'(z) = n a_n z^{n-1} + ... + a_1$ into the formula, and calculating $\int_0^{2π} \frac{p'(\gamma(t))}{p(\gamma(t))} \dot{\gamma(t)}dt$, but that looks like it would become way too complicated. Is there an elegant way (using a theorem or so) of evaluating this integral?

Comment: What you are ask to prove is (one half of) what is known as [the argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to start with the complete
*factorization* of $p$:
$$
  p(z) = a_n(z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n) \, .
$$
Then
$$
  \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{1}{z-z_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{z-z_n}
$$
and each integral
$$
 \int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{dz}{z-z_j} 
$$
can easily be computed with the [*residue theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

Alternatively, you can argue that the value of the integral does
not depend on $R$ (once that $R$ is so large that all roots of $p$ lie within $B_R(0)$). And for $ |z| \to \infty$, 
$$
  \frac{p'(z)}{p(z)} = \frac {n}{z} + O(\frac{1}{z^2})
$$

Comment: Thanks, starting with the factorization indeed looks much better. I notice that the integral $\int_{\partial B_R(0)} \frac{dz}{z-z_j}$ looks pretty much like the winding number regarding the curve parameterizing $\partial B_R(0)$ if I'm not mistaken. Does that mean that each of these integral is $2πi$? (Seeing as all the zeroes $z_j$ lie within the circle.) So, does that mean that the entire integral is equal to $2πin$, with $n$ the sum of the zeroes of $p$, or am I mistaken? (I didn't have the residue theorem in my class yet, so forgive me if using it would already answer this question.)

Comment: @moran: Yes, apart from the factor $2\pi i$ that is exactly the winding number, so the result is $n \cdot 2 \pi i$. Winding number, residue theorem  and the argument principle (mentioned in a comment to your question) are all very closely related concepts, you could use either of them here.

Comment: Ok, thanks; that's quite a nice result.